# c# refresh value on a dynamic label

Tags: c#, label, refresh, controls

i'd like to ask a question. I got this code and my intention's to make my dynamic label to refresh the value without stacking on label over another.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows.Forms;   

namespace refresh_label
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Int64 num1 = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer t1 = new Timer();
            t1.Interval = 1;
            t1.Tick += new EventHandler(lbl_refresh);
            t1.Enabled = true;
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }

        private void lbl_refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            num1++;
        }
    }
}

//on this one it's working but staking labels. is there a way to refresh the label without staking it and then clear it? thank you for your time.

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    t1.Interval = 1;
    t1.Tick += new EventHandler(lbl_refresh);
    t1.Enabled = true;
}

private void lbl_refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num1++;

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = num1.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    lbl.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: for starters there is no need to create a new label everytime. are you just wanting to create a timer and show the values in a single label..?

Comment: Can't you just lbl.Text = string.Empty; to clear, lbl.Text = newValue; to set, lbl.Invalidate; to force redraw?

Answer (score 4):

Please try this -

add the label at design time and change the code -

```
private void lbl_refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num1++;

    lbl.Text = num1.ToString();
    lbl.Update();
}
```

Comment: hello thanks, tried already but it says: the name 'lbl' does exist in the current context. i can stack the label and clear it and also remove it with controls, but for a long time running keeps stacking labels and when i clear or remove it creates flickering, thas my problem.

Comment: Declare lbl at class scope (same place you declared num1) for it to be available throughout the class.

Comment: ok it worked like charm :) thank you so much. it's working, not stacking anymore. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Int64 num1 = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        t1.Interval = 1;
        t1.Tick += new EventHandler(lbl_refresh);
        t1.Enabled = true;
        Label lbl = new Label();

        lbl.Name="myLabel";
        lbl.Text = num1.ToString();
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }

    private void lbl_refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Label l = Controls.Find("myLabel",true)[0] as Label;
       l.Text = num1.ToString();
       num1++;
     }
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry for beeing to late. Interesting, also it worked very good, anyway its a good solution for the problem. thanks :)